# Changing width and height of Alert Message i-Phone

Tags: iphone, uialertview

Was wondering what the correct way would be to initialise my alert popup with a smaller window

```
-(void)alertMessage1:(NSString*) title:(NSString*) message1  {

UIAlertView *alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Successfully uploaded!" message:message1 delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];

}
```

Comment: UIAlertView inherits from UIView, so it does have a frame property. I don't know if adjusting that will have any effect, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a UIAlertview as you suggested like this

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title Here" message:@"Message here" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
                    [alert setDelegate:self];
                    [alert show];
                    [alert release];
```

and if you want to adjust the frame them use

```
- (void)willPresentAlertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView {
alertView.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 200.f, 280.f, 93.f);
NSArray *subViewArray = alertView.subviews;
for(int x=0;x<[subViewArray count];x++){
    if([[[subViewArray objectAtIndex:x] class] isSubclassOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        UILabel *label = [subViewArray objectAtIndex:x];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
    }

}
```

}

In this **alertView.frame = CGRectMake(20.f, 200.f, 280.f, 93.f);** the CGRectMake(X-position, Y-Position, width, Height). Change it and your work will be done.

Comment: Thanks! I was also looking at changing the background color but whenever I put alert1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:...];   It changes the border not the actual background

Comment: Check another answer i posted and you can create the custon alertview by using this github.com/goncz9/GRAlertView . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom AlertView or use one of these :

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=alertview

Answer (score 0):

For the question you raised in comment **changing the background color of UIAlertview**  you can add the background image like this directly. I am not sure if you can add the color or not.

```
UIAlertView *theAlert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Atention" message: @"YOUR MESSAGE HERE", nil) delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
[theAlert show];
UILabel *theTitle = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_titleLabel"];
[theTitle setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UILabel *theBody = [theAlert valueForKey:@"_bodyTextLabel"];
[theBody setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
UIImage *theImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Background.png"];
theImage = [theImage stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:16 topCapHeight:16];
CGSize theSize = [theAlert frame].size;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(theSize);
[theImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, theSize.width, theSize.height)];
theImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
[[theAlert layer] setContents:[theImage CGImage]];
```